# Uncaught ReferenceError: XXX_default is not defined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, vite, esbuild

I have found a problem to migrate viteJs into react especially react with material ui

this is my part of code :

```
import {
  Box,
  CircularProgress,
  IconButton,
  Typography,
} from '@material-ui/core';
```

this is the error :
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNLtS.png)

i found that it is issue in vitejs but the solution there doesn't work for me  : https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1853

Any solution please ?

Comment: from what i have read on the github issue you gonna have to wait a hotfix for this import problems.
Did you have try to use `require` instead of `import` ?
Or maybe do a full import like `import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box"`

Comment: to get the similar question answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69010747/16346750)